# Firebase query observing reshowing data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, tableview

I have a firebase query that observes data from a posts child.

```swift
func fetchPosts () {

        let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryLimited(toFirst: 10)

        query.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                if let value = child.value as? NSDictionary {
                    let post = Post()
                    let poster = value["poster"] as? String ?? "Name not found"
                    let post_content = value["post"] as? String ?? "Content not found"
                    let post_reveals = value["Reveals"] as? String ?? "Reveals not found"
                    post.post_words = post_content
                    post.poster = poster
                    post.Reveals = post_reveals
                    self.postList.append(post)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
                    //make this for when child is added but so that it also shows psots already there something like query.observre event type of 
                }
            }
```

However, when a user posts something, it creates a more than one cell with the data. For instance, if I post "hello", a two new cards show up with the hello on it. However, when I exit the view and recall the fetch posts function, it shows the correct amount of cells. Also, when I delete a post from the database, it adds a new cell as well and creates two copies of it until I reload the view, then it shows the correct data from the database.

I suspect this has something to do with the observe(.value), as it might be getting the posts from the database and each time the database changes it creates a new array. Thus, when I add a new post, it is adding an array for the fact that the post was added and that it now exists in the database, and when I refresh the view it just collects the data directly from the database.

Also, sometimes the correct amount of cells show and other times there's multiple instances of random posts, regardless of whether I have just added them or not.

How can I change my query so that it initially loads all the posts from the database, and when some post is added it only creates one new cell instead of two?

Edit: The logic seeming to occur is that when the function loads, it gets all the posts as it calls the fetchPosts(). Then, when something is added to the database, it calls the fetchPosts() again and adds the new data to the array while getting all the old data. yet again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I always do when appending snapshots into an array with Firebase is check if it exists first. In your case I would add

```
    if !self.postList.contains(post) {
        self.postList.append...
```

however, to make this work, you have to make an equatable protocol for what I'm guessing is a Post class like so:

```
    extension Post: Equatable { }

      func ==(lhs: Post, rhs: Post) -> Bool {
         return lhs.uid == rhs.uid
    }
```

Comment: The first part seems like  a good solution, however, when I add the extension, I get "Redundant conformance of 'Post' to protocol 'Equatable'". Furthermore, when you set lhs.uid == rhs.uid, is the rhs.uid supposed to be the post ID or the user ID, because I am also getting the error "Value of type 'Post' has no member 'uid'" as my post class only has  var postID : String?

Comment: ".uid" is just a placeholder BTW. you need to put your own property in there

Comment: Oh, okay. What property should I put instead of .uid? I am not familiar with equatables, should I put the post id?

Comment: if your class is an NSObject it already conforms to equatable so you don't need it

Comment: Oh, okay. I tried the code without the equatable, and it works for a bit after adding posts. However, after posting again, the posts begin to duplicate again even though I have the if statement...

Comment: Hmmm. did you try: query.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in?

Comment: Also, where are you adding the post and are you calling fetch posts in viewDidAppear? if the listener is active on another viewController it will add the post and then add it again when you go back to the view controller. to check this you can add postList.removeAll() before your Firebase stuff

Comment: Yep, I fixed it by using postList.removeAll() before it appends. Thanks for your help!

Comment: there I still one small problem, when I use the postList.removeAll(), the correct number of cells shows up in the app. However in the console log, since I have  DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
                                print(self.postList) for debugging purposes, I am still seeing the repeated posts. Changing the code to   query.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                self.postList.removeAll() fixes the cells, but not the print in the console.

Comment: I think it has something to do with making 2 listeners. when you leave a viewController the old listener is still active and when you reload the view controller it calls fetchPosts which adds another listener.

Comment: Okay, I am thinking this can be fixed by removing the listeners in the ViewWillDisappear func, is there a way to remove all the listeners?

Comment: override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        ref.removeAllObservers()
    } fixed it. Working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

You are right in thinking that the `.value` event type will return the entire array each time there is a change. What you really need is the `query.observe(.childAdded)` listener. That will fetch individual posts objects rather than the entire array. Call this in your `viewDidAppear` method.

You may also want to implement the `query.observe(.childRemoved)` listener as well to detect when posts are removed.

Another way would be to call `observeSingleEvent(.value)` on the initial load then add a listener `query.queryLimited(toLast: 1).observe(.childAdded)` to listen for the latest post.

Comment: Also, when I use the  .childAdded, no posts show in the feed even when I add a new post?

Comment: Is there a way to not call .childRemoved before .childAdded if using both .childAdded & .childRemoved each with a queryLimited(toLast:)?